# ProxyProvider - how to call proxy from its sub-providers?

Tags: flutter, dart, proxy, flutter-provider

What would be the correct way to call (and pass values to) ProxyProvider from its "sub"providers?
Currently I'm passing a callback function to "sub"provider as a parameter, storing it as a Function and then I can call it when needed.
It works in a sense that ProxyProvider is called (and value is passed), but at the same time it breaks `notifyListeners()`, which is called next - searches getter in "sub"provider (and can't find it) despite that Consumer is used just for ProxyProvider.

This is the error I receive:

> error: org-dartlang-debug:synthetic_debug_expression:1:1: Error: The
> getter 'audInd' isn't defined for the class 'AudioModel'.
>
> - 'AudioModel' is from 'package:quiz_game_new/models/audioModel.dart' ('lib/models/audioModel.dart'). Try correcting the name to the name of
>   an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'audInd'.
>   audInd ^^^^^^

### Code

Provider (audioModel.dart):

```
class AudioModel extends ChangeNotifier {
    int _audioIndex = -1;
    Function? audioIndexChanged;
      
    void setCallbacks(Function _audioPlaybackCompleted, Function _audioIndexChanged) {
        audioPlaybackCompleted = _audioPlaybackCompleted;
        audioIndexChanged = _audioIndexChanged;
    }
    
    //Some code that changes _audioIndex and afterwards calls audioIndexChanged!(_audioIndex)
}
```

ProxyProvider (commonModel.dart)

```
class CommonModel extends ChangeNotifier {
    CommonModel(this.audioModel);
    final AudioModel audioModel;
    
    int _audioIndex = -1;
    int get audioIndex => _audioIndex;
    
    void setCallbacksForAudioPlayback() {
        audioModel.setCallbacks(audioPlaybackCompleted, audioIndexChanged);
    }

    void audioIndexChanged(int audInd) {
        _audioIndex = audInd;
        notifyListeners();
    }
}
```

Initialization:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
        providers: [
          ChangeNotifierProvider<STTModel>(create: (context) => STTModel()),
          ChangeNotifierProvider<QuestionModel>(
              create: (context) => QuestionModel()),
          ChangeNotifierProvider<AudioModel>(create: (context) => AudioModel()),
          ChangeNotifierProxyProvider3<STTModel, QuestionModel, AudioModel,
                  CommonModel>(
              create: (BuildContext context) => CommonModel(
                  Provider.of<STTModel>(context, listen: false),
                  Provider.of<QuestionModel>(context, listen: false),
                  Provider.of<AudioModel>(context, listen: false)),
              update:
                  (context, sttModel, questionModel, audioModel, commonModel) =>
                      CommonModel(sttModel, questionModel, audioModel))
        ],
        child: MaterialApp(
            title: 'Flutter Demo',
            initialRoute: '/',
            routes: {
              '/': (context) => ScreenMainMenu(),
              '/game': (context) => ScreenGame(),
            }));
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show how you initialized these providers?

Comment: Sure, added it at the end of question's description

Comment: Have you tried returning directly `commonModel` in `update` instead of creating a new one? I think there's no need to create a new instance in your scenario. Also, if you want to update `CommonModel`, it would be better to have a function in `CommonModel` that handles which properties to update. (e.g. `commonModel.updateSomething(...); return commonModel;`)

Answer (score 0):

> What would be the correct way to call (and pass values to)
> ProxyProvider from its "sub"providers?

I'm not a big fan of "nested" Providers : it often leads to this kind of issues and doesn't ease the readability.
In my projects, I usually use a Provider for each Feature, which I declare and Consume at the lowest level possible.
In your case, I guess I'd juste have used your `STTModel`, `QuestionModel` and `AudioModel` and would have forgotten the idea of a `CommonModel` (whom only job is is to merge all your Providers I guess?).

**You can still keep your logic, but you should take in consideration the following :**

In your `AudioModel` class, update the method where the `_audioIndex` and add a `notifyListeners()`

```
class AudioModel extends ChangeNotifier {
  //...
  int get audioIndex => _audioIndex;

  void updateIndex(int index) {
    _audioIndex = index; 
    //The rest of your code
    notifyListeners();
  } 

  //...
}
```

The creation of your Providers looks alright, but consider updating the `update` method of your `ChangeNotifierProxyProvider` for something like that :

```
update: (_, sttModel, questionModel, audioModel) => 
commonModel!..update(sttModel, questionModel, audioModel),
```

and in your CommonModel

```
 void update(SttModel sttModelUpdate, QuestionModel questionModelUpdate, AudioModel audioModelUpdate) {
    audioModel = audioModelUpdate;
    questionModel = questionModelUpdate;
    sttModel = sttModelUpdate;
    
    //Retrieve the index here from your audioModel
    _audioIndex = audioModel.audioIndex;

    notifyListeners();
  }
```

This way, whenever you call your `updateIndex` method in your `AudioModel` class, the `notifyListeners()` will update the `CommonModel` and you'll have the `_audioIndex` up to date.
And then it should work fine, no need for your callback methods anymore !

Comment: - I guess I'd juste have used your STTModel, QuestionModel and AudioModel and would have forgotten the idea of a CommonModel (whom only job is is to merge all your Providers I guess?).
Hmm, but how with such setup you would cover action chaining? I tried such approach previously, but I got stuck quite quickly. What is happening in those models:
1. QuestionModel gets URLs with audio files from the API. When it is done, then 
2. AudioModel plays audio files received in step 1. When it is done, then
3. STTModel listens to your voice and waits for input

Comment: Sorry, still getting use to how to format comments here...
How would you chain such actions with just states? Each step has a listener, which at some point should execute some method on a different model. With CommonModel (proxy provider) it kinda works, just seems a little bit odd to pass CommonModel methods to sub-providers as callback.

Comment: Your problem looks much more complicated that what you wrote down in your initial question and I'd need a lot more time and informations to define what proper architecture would be the best in your case.   
If your AudioModel depends on QuestionModel, then AudioModel should also be defined as a ChangeNotifierProxyProvider and updated whenever a new URL is retrieved.

Comment: Well, that's why I have the CommonModel in the middle - I use it to pass data around all 3 models, where it is processed and then sent back to CommonModel (not only data, also callbacks). If I'm not mistaken, then if from all those 3 models I just pass data to CommonModel and don't call notifyListeners() from them, but only in CommonModel, then those 3 models could as well be just regular classes, no need for them to be ChangeNotifiers, right?
But then it still doesn't answer my initial question - is there a better way to call CommonModel (proxyProvider) from the classes it uses?